# Why do I have to change the CallerReference on every call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, boto3

I have this Python + boto3. This code runs fine and creates a hosted zone named *test*. However when I run the same code block again with a new name say *test2*, I have to also change the CallerReference to some unique value, In the code below it will be from awsbuilder5 to awsbuilder6  etc. 
If I don't do that, I get this error:

> An error occurred (HostedZoneAlreadyExists) when calling the CreateHostedZone operation: A hosted zone has already been created with the specified caller reference.

Code is here:

```
response = client.create_hosted_zone (
  Name = 'test',
  VPC={
   'VPCRegion': 'us-east-1',
   'VPCId': 'vpc-958122f0'
  }, 
  CallerReference='awsbuilder5',
  HostedZoneConfig={
   'Comment': 'Test',
  }
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs, a CallerReference:

> A unique string that identifies the request and that allows failed
>   create-hosted-zone requests to be retried without the risk of
>   executing the operation twice. You must use a unique CallerReference
>   string every time you create a hosted zone.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/create-hosted-zone.html